# Python, Selenium find element is only by css?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to perform a login to the apple website using selenium but when looking for the ' sign in button' using the find_element_by_id I get an error implying it's a css selector,

What does that mean? I thought I was searching for the HTML element.

```py
class AppleMusicUploader:

    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER)

    def connect_to_user(self):
        self.driver.get(APPLEMUSIC_LOGIN_PAGE)
        self.wait_for_load(element_id='account_name_text_field')
        apple_id = self.driver.find_element_by_id('account_name_text_field')
        apple_id.send_keys(self.user['email'])
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(id_='sign-in').click()
        self.wait_for_load(element_id='password_text_field')
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('password_text_field')
        password.send_keys(self.user['password'])
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(id_='sign-in').click()
```

The Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="account_name_text_field"]"}
```

From the HTML Page:

```
<input type="text" class="force-ltr form-textbox form-textbox-text" id="account_name_text_field" can-field="accountName" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-required="true" required="required" spellcheck="false" ($focus)="appleIdFocusHandler()" ($keyup)="appleIdKeyupHandler()" ($blur)="appleIdBlurHandler()" placeholder="Apple&nbsp;ID" autofocus="">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the ID you want is not loading before you do your next step. Try waiting for the element to load with the following "wait_for_load" function:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class AppleMusicUploader:

    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER)

    def connect_to_user(self):
        self.driver.get(APPLEMUSIC_LOGIN_PAGE)
        self.wait_for_load('account_name_text_field')
        apple_id = self.driver.find_element_by_id('account_name_text_field')
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('password_text_field')

        apple_id.send_keys(self.user['email'])
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        password.send_keys(self.user['password'])
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.find_element_by_class_name(
            "si-button btn  fed-ui  moved   fed-ui-animation-show      remember-me  ").click()

    def wait_for_load(element_id):
        timeout = 5 # 5 second time out on loading
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, element_id))
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(element_present)
```

Comment: I get an error from the wait_for_load method
WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(element_present)
  File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/CasaBonita/ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Can you update your code to be minimally reproducible so I can your code myself? I have previously used that wait_for_load function on my own classes, so I'm surprised it's not working.